# Use the panel for layout with multiple columns

Tags: theming, 7

I created my own content type. I would like to further customize it by adding columns. I installed the module panel. Can I use the same panel layout to include my content type? Also, how do I put a picture in a field of the panel?

Answer (score 1):

I would use panels for layout of a page which contains various bits and pieces from other pages. For layout of the display of a single page or node type I would edit the templates page--content-type.tpl.php and node--content-type.tpl.php.

In node--content-type.tpl.php you could then do something like:

```
<div class="col1">
<?php
  // Hide fields so that we can render them later.
  hide($content['field_image_main']);
  print render($content); 
?>
</div>
<div class="col2">
  <?php print render($content['field_image_main']);?>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, but my main problem is to insert an image into a frame of a panel.

Comment: My feeling is that you should not be using panels for single node layout. Could you perhaps explain the need for panels?

Comment: Yes, I want to add a content type within my layouts are always different, they have various columns on the sides with different content. (images / articles that I chose on the content type)

Answer (score 1):

Following your previous comments, it seems like you want [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) rather than Panels.

> Display Suite allows you to take full control over how your content is
>   displayed using a drag and drop interface. Arrange your nodes, views,
>   comments, user data etc. the way you want without having to work your
>   way through dozens of template files. A predefined list of layouts (D7
>   only) is available for even more drag and drop fun!

There's also an absolutely cracking series of video tutorials [here](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7E361A55994F1648&feature=plcp) that will help you set it up and configure it.

Comment: If I use display suite can put the fields in regions that have previously created? If so, how?